# How do I obtain the IConfiguration parameter to instantiate a EF DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I need to instantiate the following DbContext class:

```cs
public NWBContext(DbContextOptions<NWBContext> options, IConfiguration config) : base(options) {
    Config = config;
}
```

My current code to instantiate an instance of `NWBContext` is below.

```cs
string connectionString = connString;

var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<NWBContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()                
.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"appsettings.json"))
.Build();

using (var dBContext = new NWBContext(optionsBuilder.Options, (IConfiguration)config)) {

}
```

This is for a class to import data from a CSV file into SQL. The import is too granular for a bulk insert and involves calculations that would be difficult in T-SQL.

The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#simple-dbcontext-initialization-with-new shows the following example:

```cs
var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test")
    .Options;

using var context = new ApplicationDbContext(contextOptions);
```

**The example does not address an `IConfiguration` parameter.**

How would I instantiate the `IConfiguration` parameter to pass to the `NWBContext` constructor?

Some documentation implies that `IConfiguration` could be obtained from `services`. How would I obtain `services`?

Comment: You would typically register your `DbContext` with your dependency injection framework. If you're using .NET Core, you'd register it in `Startuyp.ConfigureServices()` See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

Comment: I am doing this for an import class and need to be able to instantiate the context with a new or using.

Comment: It's still going to come down to dependency injection to solve your problems. You can inject `IHost` and then `var config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();` to get access to the `IConfiguration` that should have been set up in the configuration of your `IHostBuilder` (usually in `Program.cs`)

Comment: So it looks like the EF Core is really geared for ASP .NET Core and that the same EF Core used in ASP .NET Core App cannot be used in an admin console utility or WPF App.

Comment: If you're just building a basic console app, you don't need dependency injection and you won't have access to `IHost` or it's `Services` collection.  It looks to me like the code you're currently using to build an `IConfiguration` instance from the `appsettings.json` file should work and is about as good as you can hope for in a simple console app.  What is it about your code that isn't working, and why do you need to use `IConfiguration` in the `DbContext`?

Comment: The constructor for the `DbContext` requires a second `IConfiguration` parameter.  I could send in the output of a `ConfigurationBuilder`, but this was not properly configured.  I decided to create a standalone utility application and created a separate set EF Core context and models.  This seems to work fine.  I was hoping to have and maintain a single set of EF Core classes that could be used by ASP .NET Core as well as other .NET Core apps.  I have picked up a new course on Udemy on EF Core and Dependency Injection.  I need to complete this course to see if the same EF Core can be used...